# Integrating React application to Struts application

Tags: reactjs, struts2, react-redux

I have 2 applications. One is completely developed in React.js and the other is developed in Struts. Now I'm trying to integrate react application into struts. To achieve this i used Iframe tag and provided theReact app Url to Iframe. Are there any other options to embed react i to Struts.

Can i achieve some thing like replacing a div with react application out put as in react replacing a root div using React Dom

Comment: That's how React applications work anyway--they render a component into a DOM element. You can do the same in the S2 app. Almost certainly better than using an iframe.

Comment: I tried doing it. From build folder I've picked main.js and main.css file and added them to my project. When I run my struts application blank page appears. Any example how can I do it??